# Cross products and unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra

I am first year maths student at university.

I am currently studying cross products.

For this question,

[image]

I managed to solve the first 2 parts but am struggling with the general question at the end.

An explanation on how to solve the last one will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Recall definition of cross product $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}=ab\sin(\theta)\,\mathbf{n}$.  So $\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{q}=\sin(\angle POQ)\,\mathbf{n}$ and you know $\mathbf{n}=\pm\mathbf{k}$...

Comment: Where does the n come from. I thought the formula was just, a×b=absin(θ). What do with the n?

Comment: @Aaron $\mathbf n$ is a unit vector orthogonal to both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- You are told $|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}| = |\mathbf{a}| \,  |\mathbf{b}| \,|\sin(\theta)|$ so you can put bounds on $r$
- Your answers to the first part may suggest whether these bounds are achieved

Comment: Since $$sin(θ)$$ is between -1 and 1. Therefore r is between -a*b and a*b?

Comment: @Aaron - yes though note that, for points on the *unit* circle, $|\mathbf{a}|$ and $|\mathbf{b}|$ are both equal to $1$.  That deals with my first bullet point. Now consider my second

Comment: In this case is  sin(θ)=1?

Comment: In the first part you have five or six cases of $\sin(\theta)$, i.e. of $r$